# Create a path between two nodes through another node using cypher command in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

For example, I have three nodes a, b, c. I want to create a **path** (not relationship) between nodes a and c via node b. I referred some official docs but I cannot find exact query.

What I referred
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/#create-create-a-full-path

Comment: Keep in mind that a path is ordered nodes and relationships, that's all. You can't have a path without relationships. Creating the relationships between those nodes (whether through CREATE, MERGE, or an APOC proc) means the path exists and can be found with a MATCH on its pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.nodes/apoc.nodes.link/. This will take a list of nodes and create relationships between them to give you a path.

You could also do this with Cypher, but it's a bit more cumbersome. There's a knowledgebase article showing each method here: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/creating-and-working-with-linked-lists/.